# Unable to render plot in shinyapp

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly

I have the code below where I am trying to plot the data from a DF in shiny but the plot box is empty.

What am i doing wrong?

```
    ##----------DATA------------## 
    path <- paste0("C:/WORK/TEMP") 
    csv_path <- path 
    daily_data <-   read.table(paste0(csv_path,"/file.csv"),
                               header = T,
                               sep = ',',
                               stringsAsFactors = F) 
    daily_data$COL1 <-   as.POSIXct(daily_data$COL1, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S") 
    str(daily_data)
    ##----------END DATA------------##
    
    ## UI 
ui <- dashboardPage(   dashboardHeader(title = "Test"),   dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard"))
    )   ),   dashboardBody(
      tabItems(
        # First tab content
        tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
                fluidRow(
                  column(width = 5,
                         box(title = "Plot",
                             solidHeader = TRUE,
                             collapsible = TRUE,
                             width = 12,
                             plotOutput(outputId="myplot1")
                         )
                  )
                )
        )
      ) # end tabitems   
    ) # end dashboardbody 
    ) # end dashboardpage
    
    ## SERVER 
    server <-   function( input, output ) {   
    output$myplot1 <- renderPlotly({
    ggplotly(
      ggplot(daily_data,
             aes(
               x = COL1,
               y = COL3,
               color = COL2
             )) +
        geom_line() +
        theme_bw() +
        scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("1 mins")) +
        labs(title = "My chart ", x = "Time", y = "%")
    )
    })
    
    }
    
    shinyApp( ui = ui, server = server )
```

When I run the App, it runs fine but the plot is empty
[image]

When I run the ggplot code alone it comes clean
[image]

Comment: Try with `plotlyOutput` instead of `plotOutput`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Stefan's comment, the issue is resolved, should be using plotlyOutput instead of plotOutput.